# Emacs auto-complete for Qooxdoo?

Tags: emacs, qooxdoo

I'm starting a project using Qooxdoo and emacs with js2-mode(great tool btw) but I have a little problem: no auto complete support for the qooxdoo framework classes. Currently I have auto-complete-mode enabled, but it doesn't help when I need to remember the framework classes.

Notes:
- I'm using emacs 24.
- If needed, I can drop auto-complete-mode and use company-mode instead.

Thanks!

***Edit:*** To make this work, I did a little script to get the class names from the framework/source/class directory:

```
find . -iname '*.js' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
  grep '^qx.Class.define(".*",$' $file | sed 's/qx\.Class\.define("\(.*\)",/\1/' >> ~/.emacs.d/ac-dict/js2-mode
done
```

After that, just followed the answer from sanityinc everything worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Nice script, but you should be able to get away with just the file names, as there is a 1:1 relation between the qx/... path to the file and its class name (e.g. the path qx/util/ResourceManager.js contains the class qx.util.ResourceManager). Makes it a little easier. And be sure to -prune qx/test, as you don't want the unit test classes blowing up your dictionary. - Way to go!

Comment: @thomash Good points. If I have free time the next weeks I think I will make an improved version(the current on "stops" completing as when I type "." as in "qx.something") and post the link here and send a mail about it to the qooxdoo team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [user-defined dictionary](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#User_Defined_Dictionary) based on the major mode. First, ensure your `'ac-sources` includes `'ac-source-dictionary`. Then, create a file containing a list of the framework class names, and save it as `~/.emacs.d/ac-dict/js` (or `~/.emacs.d/ac-dict/js2-mode`).

Set the following variable in your `~/.emacs` (or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, if you are using that scheme instead, which you should ;-):

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
```

Restart your emacs, and then auto-completion candidates in .js files should include your class-names.

Comment: Nice idea! I will give it a shot and post the results later. Thanks!